# Button style in selected row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, triggers, styles

This seems as if it should be simple, but I can't make it happen... I've got a datagrid with a template column that includes a button:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Content="{Binding Path=...}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

and my linkbutton style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When the row is selected, I want to change the foreground color of the linkbutton to white or something.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                 Value="True">
          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <!-- Here be your other trigger, order matters, if it is the other way around the above trigger overrides your mouse-over trigger -->
</Style.Triggers>
```

Or something like that...

(*By the way, what about using the `DataGridHyperlinkColumn`, or at the very least just a normal `Hyperlink` instead of a `Button`?*)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot.  There's other stuff going on in the grid and in the column that forces me to use a template column.  I experimented with hyperlink when I was designing it, but couldn't get it to work.  I think it was because I needed to send a command to the viewmodel, I don't really remember at this point.